# iTunes Sync erasing Exchange calendar / contacts

Tags: exchange, iphone, apple-ios

We have had a handful of instances where corporate iPhone users will be syncing Calendar/Contacts/etc in their iTunes settings, and we would like to prevent this.

Unfortunately, when they sync their empty home Outlook calendars it then overwrites everything in their iPhone calendar. This has the unpleasant side effect up "updating" Exchange and wiping out every meeting they have. Luckily, our backups have bailed us out in each case - there seems to be no recovering from it any other way as the data is *gone*.

We prefer to allow our users to continue loading media on their phones, which we believe requires iTunes.

Is there a way, through Exchange ActiveSync or iOS mobile management, to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is certainly no way built in to Activesync as this covers a broad spectrum of manufacturers using Activesync and does not include vendor-specific options or software policies.

Also, having looked through the iPhone configuration utility, I'm not sure Apple provide a workaround either. Seeing as nowadays from iOS 5 and up a connection to itunes is not required it might be a good idea to disallow it verbally or, if music sync etc is required, possibly get your users to use itunes at work rather than at home. Unfortunately as you have no control over your employees home machines you're a bit stuck for options, there are very few policy options dictating what can and can't be done on itunes it seems.